# Trouble installing Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to Install latest version of PostgreSQL and keep running into the below problem which states -

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not be complete
>   correctly Error running sc start "PostgreSQL 10 Server":Program ended
>   with an error exit code

Other important information

- Using windows 10
- I'm not the administrator / user
- Installing version 10 "PostgreSQL-10.3-1-win64-bigsql" file from PostgreSQL website
- Running 64 bit code
- Double clicked and ran the installer file
- Symantec enterprise antivirus is installed

`bituninstaller` information is below:

> Windows Specific Configuration [23:04:29] Windows Actions (services)
>   Starting service "PostgreSQL 10 Server" Executing sc start "PostgreSQL
>   10 Server" Script exit code: 1060

Script output:

> [SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 1060: The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
>
> Script stderr: Program ended with an error exit code
>
> Error running sc start "PostgreSQL 10 Server": Program ended with an error exit code
>
> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
>
> Error running sc start "PostgreSQL 10 Server": Program ended with an error exit code
>
> [23:16:32] Running pgAdmin post installation actions
>
> Installing pgAdmin3 ... Executing C:\PostgreSQL_re/pgc install pgadmin3
>
> Script exit code: 0

Comment: "*PostgreSQL-10.3-1-win64-bigsql" is not a download from the "Postgres website"

Comment: Yes, might be coming from http://www.openscg.com/bigsql/postgresql/installers/ .

Answer (score 2):

Running an installer without administrator privileges is seldom succesful.  Why don't you follow the steps outlined here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441873/starting-postgresql-and-pgadmin-in-windows-without-installation#26441939

Comment: Thank you - I tried it; Symantec antivirus kept deleting the *.exe file. This is helpful though; I'm going to try installing it on another laptop and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: It worked finally after speding hours to try each and every solutions on SO. Thanks a ton.